# A circle shape in Madagascar

Tags: geology, volcanology, earth-history, geomorphology, mapping

I was seeing Madagascar on Google Maps and accidentally i saw a circle shape near Bebao. Coordinates are [17.4317443°E and 44.644248°S](https://www.google.com/maps/@-17.4317443,44.644248,33509m/data=!3m1!1e3).

Please, to satisfy my curiosity, can you tell me why is this shape like a circle?

Answer (score 8):

It is an extinct volcanic crater.
The location is not listed as one of the [active volcanoes in Madagascar](https://www.volcanodiscovery.com/madagascar.html).

Simplified geologic map of Madagascar ([reference](https://databasin.org/maps/new#datasets=1a187e2f29e24e98b2c4d45c109d3bb3)) shows the crater to be mapped as basaltic / Gabbro lava, [image: crater]